# how to jump from signup page to the next activity on the click of the signup button

Tags: android

ok, so I made a signup page in my application that shows up when the app starts. I used if and else statement that if none of the fields are empty, then it shows "login successful" on the click of the sign-up button on the screen else it shows"Login unsuccessful". i want to add a code in the if portion that if none of the fields are empty, then it shows"login successful" on the click of the sign up button and proceeds to the next activity which is actually the real application supposed to be displayed after the sign up page else it shows "Login unsuccessful" but can't figure out how. and I'm a beginner in android programming too.

```
 Button mShowdialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);

    mShowdialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_login,null);
            final EditText mEmail = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
            final EditText mPassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
            Button mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!mEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                            && !mPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                R.string.Success_Login_msg,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                R.string.error_login_msg,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need inside of your onclick method:

```
Button mShowdialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);

mShowdialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_login,null);
        final EditText mEmail = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final EditText mPassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        Button mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!mEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                        && !mPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                   **Context context = v.getContext();
                   context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LoggedInActivity.class));**

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            R.string.Success_Login_msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            R.string.error_login_msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }


        });



    }
});
```

Albeit, you'll need to change "LoggedInActivity.class" to the actual name of the activity you'd like to start.

Answer (score 1):

So you should use something called Intent.

```
if (login successful) {
     Intent intent = Intent(activityYourIn.this, nextactivity.class);
startActivity(intent):
}
```

Just fill out the activity your in, and the next activity. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use intents.
Create explicit intent with class name and use putExtra to pass data of username and password to that activity.